# Save checkbox state After ReLoadThe Page in JSF Primefaces

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

*Im using a "DataTable - Selection",(http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml) in primefaces 5 to check the selected rows, but when I reload the page, the checkboxes are unchecked, How can i keep the state of the checkboxes in session?*

**

*********DataTable****************

**

```
<p:dataTable  var="var" value="#{vistaBean.listaFichero}" rowKey="#{var.nombre}" paginator="true" rows="10"  
                 selection="#{vistaBean.selectFichero}">  

        <f:facet name="header">  
            Votar ProductBox 
        </f:facet>  


        <p:column  headerText="Votar" selectionMode="multiple"/>   

        <p:column headerText="Nombre del Fichero">
         <h:outputText value="#{var.nombre}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Ver/Descargar">
          <h:commandLink id="pdf" action="#{vistaBean.downLoad}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{vistaBean.ruta}" value="#{var.ruta}" />
                <h:graphicImage library="images" name="pdf.png" />
                 </h:commandLink>
        </p:column>  


    </p:dataTable>  


     <p:commandButton value="Guardar Votos" action="#{vistaBean.addVoto()}" update="msgs"/>


    <p:commandButton value="Ver Votos" update="display" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" icon="ui-icon-check" inmediate="true"/>

    <p:dialog header="Product Box Seleccionados" modal="true" showEffect="clip" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false">
        <p:outputPanel id="display">

            <p:dataList value="#{vistaBean.selectFichero}" var="v">
                #{v.nombre}

            </p:dataList>


        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>
```

Comment: Tried a newer version of PF? I remember this as an issie from looooong time ago.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue by installing a newer version of Primefaces, 5.2, i had the 5.1 and it had that bug.

Comment: Great it works now. A 5.1.x would have helped to (but that would have cost money). So next time, please do some more investigation (looking at resolved issues in PF e.g. AND immediately trying a newer version)

Answer (score -1):

This is how you set a session variable:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("foo", "bar");
```

This is how you can get session variables:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
Enumeration e = session.getAttributeNames();
while (e.hasMoreElements())
{
  String attr = (String)e.nextElement();
  System.err.println("      attr  = "+ attr);
  Object value = session.getValue(attr);
  System.err.println("      value = "+ value);
}
```

Your only task is to save the state of your checkboxes into the session and then load it.